# Rxjava scan function without initial value

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to have a scan function like this:

```
fun Observable<T>.scan(initialValueProvider: (T) -> R, accumulator: (R, T) -> R)
```

Basically it uses initialValueProvider for the first emitted value, and uses accumulator for later values.

This scan function is very similar to scanWith function, the different is I want to produce the first value from the first emitted item with initialValueProvider.

Do I need to write a custom operator for it? Or we already have some kind of combination to get that function?

Comment: do you mean [collect](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#collect-rx.functions.Func0-rx.functions.Action2-) or [reduce](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#reduce-R-rx.functions.Func2-)?

Comment: Could you use the [`startWith()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#startWith-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-) overload that takes an `Observable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a stateful transformation or write a custom operator indeed. For example:

```
Observable.defer(() -> {
    AtomicReference<R> current = new AtomicReference<>();
    return source.map(v -> {
        R acc = current.get();
        if (acc == null) {
            acc = Objects.requireNonNull(initialValueProvider.apply(v));
            current.set(acc);
        } else {
            acc = Objects.requireNonNull(accumulator.apply(acc, v));
            current.set(acc);
        }
        return acc;
    });
});
```